# How to reverse port biding (Phusion Passenger and Fastify)?

Tags: node.js, passenger, fastify

I am trying to setup a node.js app on CPanel using Phusion Passenger.
After some research I found that Phusion Passenger reverses control on the port binding.
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/nodejs/reverse_port_binding.html

There are solutions for:

- node-http-proxy
- Express.js
- Hapi.js

Express.js example:

```
if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    PhusionPassenger.configure({ autoInstall: false });
}

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var body = 'Hello World';
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);
    res.end(body);
});

if (typeof(PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
    app.listen('passenger');
} else {
    app.listen(3000);
}
```

Is it possible to setup this use case in fastify? I have looked to `FastifyListenOptions` but don't know which property should I try out.

**EDIT:**

The problem was that the default behavior of fastify is to run host as 'localhost'. Phusion passenger can only call listen once. Since 'localhost' runs both IPv4 and IPv6 it crashes. Setting to '127.0.0.1' solves this. I asked this question on a wrong premise.

Comment: You need to use the path option https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/4223

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon Unfortunately, I am hitting: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use passenger` with `{ path: 'passenger' }`.

Comment: I am also getting the error ```listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use passenger``` in a a Plesk environment. Is Fastify not compatible with passenger?

Comment: @justrusty check my edit, it might help. You don't need `PhusionPassenger.configure` nor `app.listen('passenger');` if you have a simple configuration. Just set IP to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I tried that ```fastify.listen("127.0.0.1")``` https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/4278 I just gave up in the end and found an alternative that does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By running with `fastify@4.5.3` it will work:

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })
fastify.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: 'world' }
})

if (typeof (PhusionPassenger) !== 'undefined') {
  fastify.listen({ path: 'passenger', host: '127.0.0.1' })
} else {
  fastify.listen(8080)
}
```

Note that the listen option is forwarded to the `http.createServer()` method.

[image: passenger and fastify]

Comment: I will accept this because it answers the question, however I did not solve the problem with it. The problem was that the default behavior of fastify is to run host as 'localhost'. Phusion passenger can only call listen once. Since 'localhost' runs both IPv4 and IPv6 it crashes. Setting to '127.0.0.1' solves this. I asked this question on a wrong premise.

Comment: I think it is a matter of testing versions, for this reason I wrote it. Note the source code here: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/main/lib/server.js#L44 the localhost behaviour is skipped when the `path` parameter is set

Comment: If you're using TypeScript, it will complain that it `Cannot find name 'PhusionPassenger'`.  You can solve this by declaring 
`declare const PhusionPassenger: any`;